# output buffering a function parameter

Tags: php, function, output, buffering, output-buffering

I have two simple PHP functions:

```
<? 
  function print_txt($text) {
    echo $text;
  }

  function store_data($name,$data){
    define($name,$data);
  }
?>
```

I want the second function to store data and use it later whenever I want but when I try to put the first function as a parameter it prints it directly.

E.g : `store_data('my_data',print_text('hello world'));` 
when I reload the page the 'hello world' string appears

Is there any way to keep the data and control it ? Something like output buffering maybe ?

Comment: Use `return` in first function instead of `echo`

Comment: but if i want to use only the first function to print strings / numbers it won't work ? i hope you get exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method echo do not have any return value. Return the value in print_txt after you have print it:

```
return $text;
```

Or did not I get your question?

Comment: but if i want to use only the first function to print strings / numbers it won't work ? i hope you get exactly what i want

Comment: This would work either. If you are not in an output buffering block, _print_txt($txt)_ echoes _$txt_ and returns it (the return is irrelevant). For you example `store_data('my_data',print_text('hello world'));`, 'hello world' would be echoed and saved in the constant 'my_data'.